# How to parse a simple JSON object (accessing single elements)?

Tags: json, parsing, google-apps-script, split, webhooks

I'm trying to process simple JSON data in a Google-Apps-Script (a Webhook Receiver). For a test I send data from the console:

```
curl -d "{"result":true,"count":42,"exchange":"Kroakex"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxx/exec
```

... but I can't access the json elements in my processing function:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

  console.log(jsonObj);       // ---> "{result:true,count:42,exchange:Kroakex}"
  console.log(jsonObj.count); // ---> "undefined"

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);

  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(jsonObj['count']); // ---> nothing
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(jsonObj['exchange']); // ---> nothing
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(jsonObj); // ---> {result:true,count:42,exchange:Kroakex}

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
}
```

When I instead create the JSON string manually with this line, it all works fine:

```
const jsonString = '{"result":true, "count":42, "exchange":"Kroakex"}';
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: According to The [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)  e.postData.contents is already text so why use stringify on it?

Comment: Thank you, you may be right... but when I leave the line out I get an error "unexpected token at position 0" at the following parsing line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modification points:

- I think that in your curl command, there are the modification points.

  1. When your curl command is used, `e.postData.contents` is `"{result:true,count:42,exchange:Kroakex}"`. Because at `-d "{"result":true,"count":42,"exchange":"Kroakex"}"`, `"` is used in `"{,,,}"`. In this case, your Google Apps Script cannot parse the values as JSON object. Please escape `"` or enclose by `'`. By this, `e.postData.contents` becomes `"{\"result\":true,\"count\":42,\"exchange\":\"Kroakex\"}"`.
  2. In this case, please use `-L` and `-X POST` is not required.
  3. The modified curl command is as follows.

     ```
      curl -L -d '{"result":true,"count":42,"exchange":"Kroakex"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec
     ```

  - or

    ```
      curl -L -d "{\"result\":true,\"count\":42,\"exchange\":\"Kroakex\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec
    ```

By above modification, your Google Apps Script becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);  // <--- Modified

  console.log(jsonObj);
  console.log(jsonObj.count);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);

  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(jsonObj['count']);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(jsonObj['exchange']);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));  // <--- Modified

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
}
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- When you use the curl command, I think that the returned value might be suitable for `return ContentService.createTextOutput("post request received");` instead of `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");`.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

### Added:

When you want to access to Web Apps using the URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev`, it is required to use the access token. The modified curl command is as follows.

```
curl -L \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"result":true,"count":42,"exchange":"Kroakex"}' \
  "https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/dev"
```

- In this case, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` can be used for the scope.

#### Reference:

- [How to use dev mode from outside](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#how-to-use-dev-mode-from-outside)

Comment: ohhhh thank yoouuu!!! :-D thank you so much... you saved my day!! I followed your instructions and it works as expected now. Maybe you also know how I can make use of the ".../dev" webhook url (instead of ".../exec")? It would be so great if I won't have to redeploy a new Web App version after every tiny code change...

Comment: @cody Thank you for replying. About your new question, I added one more curl sample command. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: oh, I forgot, now confirmed, thx! :-) I see, I need a token... as you described in the reference I can retrieve a token by calling "ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()" ... but what do I do with it then? Shall I open a new topic here to ask you this question? :-)

Comment: @cody Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question of `but what do I do with it then?`, if you want to use `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`, please use the retrieved access token to `-H "Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###"`. In this case, the expiration time of token is 1 hour. Please be careful this. If I misunderstood your question and you cannot understand about it, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad.

Comment: Ok, I ask in other words: My dev-webhook is triggered and my funktion fetches an AuthToken. Now I'd like to update a spreadsheet with incoming JSON data. How do I use that token for that? I mean, how can I code that in the doPost() function? I'd like to make it use the token automatically (without having to send any further commands manually)...?

Comment: @cody Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about the detail of your current situation from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. And also, I think that your new questions are different from your this question. So can you post it as new question by including more information. By this, I would like to think of the issue and solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.